# ajax no me esta enviando mensaje registro

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Cordial saludo

Buenos dias tengo un proyecto que estoy realizando pero cuando realizo la inserccion de usuario con ajax no me devuelve el mensaje por alert o por sweetalert confirmo en la base de datos y ha realizado la inserccion de nuevo usuario

codigo js

```js
function NuevoUsuario(nombre,apellido,email,usuario,pass,perfil,estado)
{
  /*var nuevo={
     nombre:nombre,
     apellido:apellido,
     email:email,
     usuario:usuario,
     pass:pass,
     perfil:perfil,
     estado:estado
  };*/
  var nuevo="nombre="+nombre+"&apellido="+apellido+"&email="+email+"&usuario="+usuario+"&pass="+pass+"&perfil="+perfil+"&estado="+estado;
  $.ajax({
      method:"POST",
      url:"../Controller/add.php",
      data:nuevo,
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(r)
      {
        if(r.add){
           alert("registrado"+r.msg);
            /*(Swal.fire({
                position:'top-end',
                icon:'success',
                title:'Se ha agregado un nuevo usuario',
                showConfirmButton:false,
                timer:1500
            })+r.msg;
            */
           
        }else{
            /*
            Swal.fire({
                position: 'top-end',
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Error de registro'
            })+r.msg;
            */
        }
        return false;
      }
  });
  


}
function limpiardatos()
{
    nombre=$('#nombre').val("");
    apellido=$('#apellido').val("");
    email=$('#email').val("");
    usuario=$('#usuario').val("");
    pass=$('#pass').val("");
    //perfil=$('#perfil').val("");
    //estado=$('#estado').val("");
}
```

aqui anexo el codigo html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>registro</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="../../public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../../public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/usuarios.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
    

  
   
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around mt-3">
            <div class="card col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
               <article class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-4 mt-1 text-center">Registro de Usuario</h4>
               </article>
                <form method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                         <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Apellido</label>
                         <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Correo Electronico</label>
                         <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electronico">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Usuario</label>
                         <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Password</label>
                         <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="******">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="estado">Perfil:</label> 
                    <select name="perfil" id="perfil" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione perfil de usuario</option>
                        <option value="1">admnistrador</option>
                        <option value="2">docente</option>
                        <option value="2">estudiante</option>
                    </select> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="estado">Estado:</label> 
                        <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Seleccione estado del usuario</option>
                            <option value="1">Activo</option>
                            <option value="2">Inactivo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btnGuardar"  >Registrarse</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
   
    
  </body>
</html>
```

codigo script usado para la inserccion del nuevo usuario

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnGuardar').click(function(){
            var nombre=$('#nombre').val();
            var apellido=$('#apellido').val();
            var email=$('#email').val();
            var usuario=$('#usuario').val();
            var pass=$('#pass').val();
            var perfil=$('#perfil').val();
            var estado=$('#estado').val();
            //e.preventDefault();
            limpiardatos();
            NuevoUsuario(nombre,apellido,email,usuario,pass,perfil,estado);
        });
    });
</script>
```

codigo del modelo

> public function addUsers($Nombre, $Apellido
> ,$Correo,$Usuario,$Password,$Perfil,$Estado)
> {
> $statement=$this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name,last_name,email,usuario,password,perfil,estado)
> VALUES(:nombre,:apellido,:correo,:usuario,:pass,:perfil,:estado)");
> $statement->bindParam(':nombre',$Nombre);
> $statement->bindParam(':apellido',$Apellido);
> $statement->bindParam(':correo',$Correo);
> $statement->bindParam(':usuario',$Usuario);
> $statement->bindParam(':pass',$Password);
> $statement->bindParam(':perfil',$Perfil);
> $statement->bindParam(':estado',$Estado);
> if($statement->execute() && $statement->rowCount()>0){
> $r=array("add"=>true,"msg"=>"se han agregado los datos:".$statement->rowCount());
> //header('Location:../Pages/add.php');
> }else{
> $r=array("msg"=>"No se agregaron los datos");
> }
> echo json_encode($r);
> }

Controller

```
<?php
 require_once('../Model/Usuarios.php');
if($_POST)
{
   $Nom=$_POST['nombre'];
   $Ape=$_POST['apellido'];
   $Corre=$_POST['email'];
   $Usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
   $Pass=$_POST['pass'];
   $Perfi=$_POST['perfil'];
   $Estado=$_POST['estado'];
   $modelousuarios = new Usuarios();
   $modelousuarios->addUsers($Nom,$Ape,$Corre,$Usuario,$Pass,$Perfi,$Estado);
}
?>
```

[image: el codigo esta en false y en el js esta console.log pero no me muestra nada]

controller

```
 public function addUsers($Nombre, $Apellido ,$Correo,$Usuario,$Password,$Perfil,$Estado)
     {
        $statement=$this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name,last_name,email,usuario,password,perfil,estado) 
        VALUES(:nombre,:apellido,:correo,:usuario,:pass,:perfil,:estado)");
        $statement->bindParam(':nombre',$Nombre);
        $statement->bindParam(':apellido',$Apellido);
        $statement->bindParam(':correo',$Correo);
        $statement->bindParam(':usuario',$Usuario);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass',$Password);
        $statement->bindParam(':perfil',$Perfil);
        $statement->bindParam(':estado',$Estado);
        if($statement->execute() && $statement->rowCount()>0){
            $r=array("add"=>true,"msg"=>"se han agregado los datos:".$statement->rowCount());
            //header('Location:../Pages/add.php');
          }else{
              $r=array("error"=>false,"msg"=>"No se agregaron los datos");
          }
          echo json_encode($r);
     }
```

correpciones de prueba inclusion codigo javascript en html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>registro</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="../../public/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
    

  
   
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-around mt-3">
            <div class="card col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
               <article class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title mb-4 mt-1 text-center">Registro de Usuario</h4>
               </article>
                <form method="POST" id="Usuarios">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                         <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Apellido</label>
                         <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Correo Electronico</label>
                         <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electronico">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Usuario</label>
                         <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Password</label>
                         <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="******">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="estado">Perfil:</label> 
                    <select name="perfil" id="perfil" class="form-control">
                        <option value="0">Seleccione perfil de usuario</option>
                        <option value="1">admnistrador</option>
                        <option value="2">docente</option>
                        <option value="2">estudiante</option>
                    </select> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="estado">Estado:</label> 
                        <select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control">
                            <option value="0">Seleccione estado del usuario</option>
                            <option value="1">Activo</option>
                            <option value="2">Inactivo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                     <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btnGuardar"  >Registrarse</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    
    
  </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnGuardar').click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var datos=$('#Usuarios').serialize();
           // alert(datos);
          
            $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"../Controller/add.php",
            data:datos,
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(r)
             {
                 if(r.add){
                    alert("Exito!"+r.msg);    
                 }else{
                    alert("Fallo"+r.msg);
                 }
                
                
          
      
            } 
        });
            //var nombre=$('#nombre').val();
             //var apellido=$('#apellido').val();
            // var email=$('#email').val();
            // var usuario=$('#usuario').val();
            // var pass=$('#pass').val();
            // var perfil=$('#perfil').val();
             //var estado=$('#estado').val();
            //e.preventDefault();
            //limpiardatos();
            //NuevoUsuario();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

el resto del codigo del controlador y del modelo siguen igual no han sido modificado de momento. estoy recien comenzando en el mundo de la programación

Comment: Hola, deberías incluir el erro que se muestra por consola a la hora de mostrar la alerta y además incluir de mejor manera tu código de PHP

Comment: Saludos. El detalle es que (conforme a la imagen que proporcionas del PHP) para siempre devuelves `"add"=>false` (uno de los dos debiera ser `true`); ahora bien particularmente yo ejecutaria primero el `->execute()` y luego evaluaría el `->rowCount()` te sugiero armar el SQL que se ejecuta y usarlo para probar con los datos que se pasan. El detalle puede este en el `"Controller/add.php"` que no incluiste; más que nada por los datos o forma que se pasan.

Comment: inclui el codigo del controlador el cual era que hacia falta

Comment: En lugar de pantallazos, incluye código por favor :D